# he was struck/knocked/hit

Tags: meaning, verbs, adverbs

1. He was knocked on his ass.
2. He was struck on his ass.
3. He was hit on his ass.

Which mean

a) a blow was delivered to his ass

and which mean

b) he was struck and fell on his ass

Many thanks

Comment: I wouldn't understand any of them to mean (b).

Comment: This might be a regional or dialect difference.  In US English, "He was knocked on his ass" would mean (b), but never (a).

Comment: @stangdon I disagree; I also speak American English and would interpret "He was knocked on his ass" as an awkward way of saying (a). If I wanted to say (b), I would say "knocked down," not just "knocked."

Comment: @alphabet. If you do a Google Books search for "knocked on his ass", it's not an uncommon phrase, and always seems to mean (b).

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the difference between '*on*' and '*onto*'.

Broadly speaking, if you're hit *on* something, that is the location of the strike. Context is important because it could mean the location on your body where you were stuck (eg "*someone hit me on the head*") or your general location when you were hit (eg "*some kid hit me on the bus*"). If you're hit *onto* something, that is the thing you land on.

Of course, '*he fell on his ass*' can only mean that he landed on his ass because it is part of the body and you can't fall onto it any other way. If you wanted to include this information and state the location of his fall you'd say something like "*he fell on the ground and landed on his ass*".

It becomes necessary to use 'onto' to remove ambiguity. Your examples are ambiguous, so you need to use either 'on' or 'onto' depending on what you mean.

There is a potential ambiguity when you say something like '*he fell on the grass*' because it could be taken to mean you either landed on the grass or that you fell while you were standing on it, but as the outcome is the same (you're bound to land on the thing you were standing on when you fell), it isn't an issue.